# Random Image Display, Without Repeat, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I know there are already a few questions like this, but I just can't seem to apply any of the answers (this is my first time making anything like this at all).  I currently have a page that, when a button is pushed, a random image appears (thanks to some of the great posts on here, this is actually working).  My issue is, the random number has a lot of repeats prior all the images being seen.  I am wanting to make it where all images are seen (in a random order) before any duplicates.  This is what is in the body:

```
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
   <tr align="center">
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Click Here">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript">

var imagesArray = [
'images/img-1.jpg',
'images/img-2.jpg',
'images/img-3.jpg',
'images/img-4.jpg',
'images/img-5.jpg',
];

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));

    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];

    }

</script>
```

From what I have read, the way to do this would be to add a spice, and have shown images dropped into a new array, then once the original array equals 0, then have it reset.  Try as I might, I have not been able to successfully integrate that into my code :( .  This is what I ended up with (which does nothing, and breaks the function entirely):

```
<script>

var imagesArray = [
'images/img-1.jpg',
'images/img-2.jpg',
'images/img-3.jpg',
'images/img-4.jpg',
'images/img-5.jpg',
];

var shownImages = []

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];

    shownImages.unshift(imagesArray.splice(num,num+1));

    if(images.length == 0){
     images.Array = shownImages;
     shownImages = [];

     return shownImages[0];

    }
</script>
```

Another method mentioned seemed to be to have a function that shuffled the images first, then displayed them in the shuffled order, then reshuffled and repeated, but I got even less far with that.

There also seems to be some question on whether the random number max should be imagesArray.length by itself, or +1 or -1.  I am sure there are a number of other issues with this as well, but like I said, this is my first attempt. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://michiel.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/how-to-shuffle-an-array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of the numbers that you have generated, and if its a repeat then get a new number.

```
<script language="javascript">

var imagesArray = [
'images/img-1.jpg',
'images/img-2.jpg',
'images/img-3.jpg',
'images/img-4.jpg',
'images/img-5.jpg',
];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        usedImagesCount++;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: That definitely stopped the repeats, but once the last image was displayed, clicking again doesn't seem to start the images over again in a new random order.  The button just stops doing anything after that.

Comment: Ahh, it works.  There was a small typo in that  "usedImagedCount++;" should have been " usedImagesCount++;"

Thanks so much!!