# random image with Javascript without repeating

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, random, repeat

Have been searching with Google got loads of result but not that I can successfully implement.

I use these code from [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut118.shtml) to display a random image from an array.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()

myimages[1]="image1.gif"
myimages[2]="image2.gif"
myimages[3]="image3.gif"
myimages[4]="image4.gif"
myimages[5]="image5.gif"
myimages[6]="image6.gif"

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1

document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}

random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

The script works very well but the images repeat itself sometimes (e.g. img6.gif -> img4.gif -> img4.gif), would like to have the images display without duplicate with the previous one.

I'm not very familiar with javascript as well as programming and this is my first time to play around with such, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: A _random_ number doesn't mean it is **unique**, especially when generating a small random number.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: Floor floors a random number to `0`. You're missing `myimages[0]` - Also that's not the preferred way to coustruct an Array

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for reminding me, will bear in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

A general answer: I think the way the random function works makes it so you can't skip repeating images unless you remove the image that you used from the array. So an idea could be to make your array a global variable outside of the function and remove the image that you already used. And then in your main function, if the array is of size zero after  a removal, you can reload the array with your original set of images. Just an idea, try it out if your having trouble :)

Comment: My method would also leave a slight chance to duplicate the image on the array reload as well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Chris, it clear me up quite a lot, I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496746/random-image-display-without-repeat-with-javascript) but it involved a button so still figuring out how could I bring this work with my code...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array where you can store ids that you've already used.
And then you need to find random id which is not in this array.

Here you have example code:

```
var usedIds = [];
...

var ry = 0;
if(userIds.length != myimages.length) { 
    // If we haven't used all the images
    do {
        ry = Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);
    } while (usedIds.indexOf(ry) > -1);

    // here we have new randomized and unique image id
    usedIds.push(ry);
    // do something with new id
} else {
    // we have already used all the images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var intervalID;
var showed = {};
var loopCount = 0;

function random_imglink(){
    var myimages=new Array()

    myimages[1]="image1.gif"
    myimages[2]="image2.gif"
    myimages[3]="image3.gif"
    myimages[4]="image4.gif"
    myimages[5]="image5.gif"
    myimages[6]="image6.gif"

    var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);
    
    if (ry===0) ry=1;
  
      var src = myimages[ry]
      document.body.innerHTML+=('<br>' +  Object.keys(showed).length + '/' +  myimages.length);
  
      // if all images showed 
      if( Object.keys(showed).length === myimages.length - 1 ){
        //                                              |___|
        //                                                ^
        //                                                |
        // this is what i modified -----------------------+
        
        
        
        //we reset the showed cache
        showed = {};
        
        // we increment the loopCount
        loopCount = loopCount + 1;
        if(loopCount === 3 ){
          
          clearInterval( intervalID );
          return;
        }
        document.body.innerHTML+=('<hr>incremting loopCount<hr>');
        
      }
  
      // if this src have been showed we random_imglink;
      if( showed[src] ) return random_imglink();
      
      document.body.innerHTML+=('<br>img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>');
      
      
      //we store the showed img
      showed[src] = true;
}
document.body.innerHTML+=('we start : <br>');

intervalID = setInterval( random_imglink , 500)
```

---

I dont know about you constraints, but if you own the code and you can modify it like you want / need, 
and once you understand that the way above is not the more optimized, maybe you should consider this version below !

```js
var id;
var i = 0;
var loopCount = 0;

var myimages=[];

// we want a clone array of your myimages[]
// because we want modify it, and keep safe the original.
// it will be copied later
var clonedImages ; 

myimages.push("image1.gif");
myimages.push("image2.gif");
myimages.push("image3.gif");
myimages.push("image4.gif");
myimages.push("image5.gif");
myimages.push("image6.gif");
//       ^
//       |
// Don't have to worry about images index
// Just push in the array in the order you need.


function ran_link(){
  
  // if we have no clone or clone is empty
  // we create it
  if(! clonedImages || ! clonedImages.length ){
    
    
    if(loopCount >= 3) {
      clearInterval(id);
      return;
    }
    
    // we create a clone of myImages
    clonedImages = myimages.slice(0 , myimages.length);
    loopCount= loopCount + 1;
    
    
    document.body.innerHTML+=('<br> loop : ' + loopCount);
    i=0;
  }
  
  // We work here only with the existant element 
  //                                        |
  //                                        V
  var ry =Math.floor(Math.random() * clonedImages.length);
  
  // we extract the element from the array
  // so the array.length will be -1
  var currentImage = clonedImages.splice(ry,1);
  
  // currentImage is an array of 1 element
  // we get the value at index 0
  var currentImageURL = currentImage[0];
  
  document.body.innerHTML+=('<br>' + (i++) + ' : ' + currentImageURL  + ' <==> ' + ry);
  return cur;
  
}


id = setInterval(ran_link , 500);
```

Comment: Yes your right ! now it works, ihave modified my answer to fit your needs  !

Comment: Thanks! The script works but it seems like the cache part doesn't work as expect and the images still repeats before all of them have been shown. Not sure is the "Object.keys" cause the issue since other function e.g. "Math.floor", "Math.random", "document.write" will be highlighted in different text color but the "keys" in the "Object.keys" remain white in color likes variables such as "var", "src", "ry". Too new to js to understand is this the issue...

Comment: Yes you're right ! i omitted that your image array start at 1 and not 0. I updated my answer with a working example see it and tell me !

Comment: I have added a second version more optimized, just check it and tell me !