# Multiple random images per page, without repeat

Tags: javascript, php, image, random

So, I need to display 2 or 3 different images in a website, as simple parallax dividers for content.

I have an array of 4 images, so I'll be able to randomize without repeat them in the same page, althoug the random won't be that noticeable.

I've been lurking this for a while, and found these

[Random Image Display, Without Repeat, with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496746/random-image-display-without-repeat-with-javascript)

```
<script language="javascript">
    var imagesArray = [
        'images/img-1.jpg',
        'images/img-2.jpg',
        'images/img-3.jpg',
        'images/img-4.jpg',
        'images/img-5.jpg',
    ];

    var usedImages = {};
    var usedImagesCount = 0;

    function displayImage() {

        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
        if (!usedImages[num]) {
            document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
            usedImages[num] = true;
            usedImagesCount++;
            if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length) {
                usedImagesCount = 0;
                usedImages = {};
            }
        } else {
            displayImage();
        }
    }
</script>
```

(this was created to exhibit the image upon a click on a button, as it follows

```
<input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Click Here">
```

I tried to adapt it to my need, but the call on my page din't produce any results)

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/266181/random-imageslinks-without-repeating

(this one, I couldn't quite understand why, but I wasn't able to apply the solution. not sure if it's the code or the way of calling the image that's wrong...)

http://www.utopiamechanicus.com/article/not-so-random-image-rotation-in-php-for-html-the-sequel/

```
<?php
    // rotate images randomly but w/o dups on same page - format:
    // <img src='rotate.php?i=0'> - rotate image #0 - use 'i=1'
    // for second, etc
    // (c) 2004 David Pankhurst - use freely, but please leave in my credit
    $images = array(// list of files to rotate - add as needed
        "img1.gif",
        "img2.gif",
        "img3.gif",
        "img4.gif",
        "img5.gif");
    $total = count($images);
    $secondsFixed = 10; // seconds to keep list the same
    $seedValue = (int) (time() / $secondsFixed);
    srand($seedValue);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total;  ++$i) { // shuffle list 'randomly'
        $r = rand(0, $total - 1);
        $temp = $images[$i];
        $images[$i] = $images[$r];
        $images[$r] = $temp;
    }
    $index = (int) ($_GET['i']); // image index passed in
    $i = $index % $total; // make sure index always in bounds
    $file = $images[$i];
    header("Location: $file"); // and pass file reference back
?>
```

(this one was supposed to work calling through:

```
<img src='mysite.com/rotate.php?i=0'>
```

but the images are still repeating themselves sometimes)

They didn't work for me, so I decided to start a new topic, because I'm really newbie (actually, I don't know writing nothing at all) at javascript, and can't figure out what's the best approach. I understood it would be something like randomize the items, assign each of them a position (a number, a character, a [i], etc), and then call for it in my php page. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: `I don't know writing nothing at all` This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: what is wrong with all these examples, what do you need in addition?

Comment: Sorry. I've cleared up everything a little bit now, about my needs. I'm not asking for someone to teach from a,b,c (although that's I'd need, but yeah, this is a not a tutorial site, everything has its own time and place), just to help me to adapt those solutions to my need.

Comment: so you want php, not with javascript?

Comment: @mitkosoft It actually doesn't really matter. If Javascript produces what I need, and I be able to call the image on the website in wherever position I want to, I might use Javascript. It's just that this is the language I know the less, but if someone helps me to get where I need... no problem! :) It's difficult to verbalize my need cause I don't know the best way to get there, but I just need to randomize some images, and then call them without repeating them on the same page.

Comment: just to clarify - you want a script which to be called trough `<img src="">`? because otherwhise you simply can define an array of images into your page, and to use `shuffle()` function in PHP in order to get random order of this array.

Comment: @mitkosoft yeah that's pretty much right. But what I want is that, once called, it produces an image, and when I call it again, a little bit further on the page, it will produce a new image, with no chance to repeat the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is that you want but this will give you randomized images (without repeat) on a page, every time different ones:

```
<?php
    $img = array('img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png', 'img4.png', 'img5.png', 'img6.png');
    shuffle($img);
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
        print '<img src="'.$img[$i].'"><br>';
    }
?>
```

If you want to receive one image per call, one of the possible solutions is to use session:

***image.php:***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function getImage() {
        $img = array('img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png', 'img4.png', 'img5.png');
        shuffle($img);
        foreach($img as $key => $val) {
            if (!is_array($_SESSION['img'])) {
                return $val;
            } elseif (count($_SESSION['img']) >= count($img)) {
                $_SESSION['img'] = array();
            }
            if (is_array($_SESSION['img']) && !in_array($val, $_SESSION['img'])) {
                return $val;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

***page.php:***

```
<?php
    include 'image.php';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $currImg = getImage();
        $_SESSION['img'][] = $currImg;
        echo $currImg . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

All displayed images are stored into SESSION variable. When all images are displayed, this SESSION var is reset and will start a new cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much for it! But the thing is, you script is generating 3 images on my page, where I put it. What I need is to produce 1 image per call, that won't repeat any of the previously ones on the same page.

p.s.: Thank you very very much for your patience and will to help

Comment: Not sure If I applied the code correctly, though, I'm really sorry if I didn't, but I tried to apply it directly and tried to correct it, but wasn't able of doing so.

Comment: I've put second option by using `SESSION` variable, check it. This approach is suitable also for multi pages, is enough just to include `image.php` on very top of each page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But I don't think I'm being able to apply it again, I'm really sorry.
I'm supposed to create a new page called image.php, and them use that code page.php in wherever place I want to render a image, is that correct? If it is, I got an error


    'Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/iguacusustentabilidade/www/cursos-e-treinamentos.php:99) in /home/iguacusustentabilidade/www/divs.php on line 2'

Comment: So I tried to put it on the top of the page, then it rendered 3 paths to my image files as texts. So, after some trials I was able to use a part of the code on the top of page, including the page, and then call to render a image on the position I wanted it, but again, once I used more than one call per page, sometimes it was repeating. I'm really sorry, but could you detail me how to apply the codes? Cause I understand your code is actually right, but I'm not applying it correctly.