# Fast playback of images via JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to find a way of playing a cycle of images and hyperlinks via JS or CSS (not sure which would work), in a similar fashion to how a GIF animation functions.

I would ordinarily use a GIF for something like this, but I’m wanting to randomise the order the images are shown with each page refresh (plus I wouldn’t know how to have different hyperlinks for specific frames in a GIF).

Thank you very much, I hope this makes sense

Comment: Are you looking for a [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) or slideshow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random Image Display, Without Repeat, with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496746/random-image-display-without-repeat-with-javascript)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do something like this with JavaScript:

```
var index=0;
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
    function changeBanner() { 
      [].forEach.call(images, function (v,i) {
          images[i].hidden = i!==index
      });
      index = (index+1) % images.length;
    }
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(changeBanner, 1000)
};
```

And your HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="1.png" width="640px" height="480px" class="slideshow" />
<img src="2.png" width="640px" height="480px" class="slideshow"  />
<img src="3.png" width="640px" height="480px" class="slideshow"  />
<img src="4.png" width="640px" height="480px" class="slideshow"  />
```

This increments `i` each second, and removes the `hidden` attribute from the `<img>` element with the `src` of `i.png`.

Comment: I didn't say anything when I down-voted this, but now that it's been accepted I must point out that this code is far from optimal.  First and foremost, it assumes that every image in the document should be part of the playback.  At least assume an array of images other than `document.images` or if that is not deemed necessary, declare a variable to refer to `document.images` instead of referring directly to `document.images` 3 separate times.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty OK, I'll change it, will you upvote me if it's better, or at least remove the downvote?

Comment: Yes that's better

Comment: This code works well for me, but I was wondering if it would be possible to randomise the order in which the images are displayed on every page reload? At the moment it always play in the same sequence

Comment: Maybe use `Math.random` to call a random index from an array?